# MYSQL storing HTML block vs subdividing and creating tables for children

Tags: html, mysql

I'm creating blocks of `contenteditable` DIVs that contain DIVs of text blocks and SPANs around individual words or phrases. The SPANs were being saved to the database as separate entities. I did not see the need to subdivide and create separate tables and columns in order to avoid using html code (I have no idea whether this or that is good practice).

Now that my ideas have ran rampant, I'm wondering whether in fact it will be better to store every wrapper, child div and span as separate entities in the database, along with associated properties. It might take a bit to set up, but I'm wondering about the pros and cons of one approach vs the other.

For example, is having different bits of data stored in different tables and rows ultimately slower, more difficult to manage in the long run and more susceptible to getting 'corrupted' than having it all in one field?

An example block of HTML:

```
<div class="tab" id="tab1" contenteditable=true>
        <div>
            ly dummy text <span id="1">of</span> the pri
        </div>
        <div>
            ly dummy <span id="2">text</span> of the pri
        </div>
        <div>
            ly <span id="3">dummy</span> text of the pri
        </div>
        <div>
            ly dummy <span id="4">text</span> of the pri
        </div>
        <div>
            <span id="5">ly</span> dummy text of the <span id="6">pri</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Previously, I would load the whole block of HTML and allow client side functions to do something with the spans. Now, I'm wondering what the drawbacks would be of not only storing the separate `tabs` but also every child div of that tab and the numerous possible spans within those divs in relationship tables. So, Context > Tab > Div > Span, and the multiple thousands of rows that could result in in a given table. Unfortunately, I am relatively new to programming, so am uncertain about some of these principles. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: If you actually want to downvote this legitimate question, the least you can do is give a reason for why it didn't meet your standards of what a question should be. Thanks

Comment: It's too broad. When you're talking about code you've written it's important to include a representative sample so we can understand the context. This is also a subjective sort of question, there's many possible solutions and we can't tell what's best because we don't know all your considerations. What is "slower"? Is it really a problem?

Comment: It's broad and without code because I am literally interested in the theory, and if it is subjective, then that's also good to know, because I really have no idea being relatively new to this stuff. Let me edit...

Comment: This question is more discussion based, and Stack Overflow is focused on questions with technical answers, not opinion-based ones, as valid as those might be. It's not that you have a bad question, it's just not on-topic.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case. It's a pity, really, because a lot of confusion and misunderstanding in this field comes from not having a good feel for basic principles - then there would be fewer basic 'how to' questions. Wouldn't Stack want to cater to such types of discussions, with all the good will that DOES exist on this site from contributors?

Comment: @MikeyB it is not the principles that should guide you, but your business requirements. You should ask yourself: is there any business requirement that can only be satisfied by storing these components of data separately? The answer determines the approach you have to take.

Comment: Stack Overflow tries to stay focused on specific technical problems that have concrete solutions, not things that are "it depends" in nature. For more open-ended debate there are other places, like Reddit's /r/programming, which has a proper threading system, plus the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) here. You may find that a mentoring or coaching try service like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com) is the best way to understand on a deeper level.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for the answer. That's exactly where I'm coming from - I'm trying to ascertain what would be most efficient for my business; retrieving one block of text, or subdividing the block into rows which are in turn subdivided into more rows. Intuitively, I would say the single block is 'more efficient', but then maybe I don't understand the principles and efficiencies involved in relational databases, which is very likely. Hence, I thought this might be the place to go for an experienced view on that.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for posting suggestions. Like I say, I didn't know whether this was a concrete thing or not, hence I asked. I gave a bit of an example but maybe it's not enough to give any clue as to where that line should be drawn, as far as determining whether one approach is clearly more efficient than the other. I'll check out your links and get to grips with what Obsidian Age posted below. We got there in the end (but then more knowledge is always more helpful;)

Comment: Sometimes it's subjective, and people get kind of touchy about it. I wouldn't worry about a down-vote here or there, it all works out in the end.

Comment: @MikeyB The problem is that learning about principles and general good practices is one thing, applying them to a specific problem is another. Whilst Obdidian Age's answer may describe a **general** approach, you may very well have to follow a different route in your **specific** application. This is why this question and answer below is not useful for SO. This is simply not a platform to discuss such high level concepts.

Comment: Gamifying this stuff and turning it into facebook style is completely stupid and counterproductive, imo. I couldn't care less about the points. It's more of an attitude thing that bugged me and the signaled willingness *not* to help, when all I want to do is learn. And now, rather than talking about my question at hand, we've spent all this time talking about why I should or shouldn't have written something. Ironic :)

Comment: Well, I also find it ironic that you come to a community for help, do not even bother to check if your question is something that the community endorses, and when you are reminded of those rules, you pretend to be completely innocent.

Comment: Haha, can you point me to the list of questions that are endorsed by the community? You see, the word 'vague' is also vague, as different people have different interpretations of what vague is. I thought, especially after the edit, that I had specified it precisely enough to have someone with more experience than I to be able to catch on to what I was saying and point me in the right direction. Genuinely, I know of the lofty standards here so wanted to ask something technical enough that there might be an answer to. It's not my fault for not knowing that there wasn't ;)

Comment: The great thing about being ignorant is you can't cure stupid. Getting downvotes is fine; too many people take organic ones personally, but they shouldn't be. You'll get the hang of how the community here works soon enough. I think the SE site you were looking for may be Programmers Exchange, as well.

Comment: Also, and this is probably a big topic, but it's possible you would benefit from reading about Content Strategy and primarily the content management and channel distribution aspects.

Comment: @Jared Alright man, now we're getting somewhere. One way or another we get where we want to go, or at least get pointed in the direction there. Appreciated. I might scope out the vibe on PE but, with your second post, you made me realize this decision about data structure can't/shouldn't be made casually in the course of one evening's coding. I'll read up on the theory and contemplate it some more (before I dare open my mouth again;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing whole sections of HTML into a database is generally bad practice; you shouldn't really be storing **any** markup in a database unless you're specifically wanting different views for different users. Even then I would be recommending having multiple different HTML pages instead.

Instead, what you should be doing is considering your HTML to be a **representation** of the data stored in the database, and treating the two as entirely independent. The respresentation is how you '`view`' the data, and should simply denote how your data is **presented**.

Assuming your users can edit your blocks of content so that others will be able to see the changes, you *may* want to store the **text** that the user types into the database, though you certainly don't want to store any of the supporting HTML formatting in the database.

When you want to display this information back to the user, you simply **inject** the infroamtion retrieved from the database into the view.

For example (in PHP):

```
<html>
  <div class="container">
    <span id="output"><?php echo $content; ?></span>
  </div>
</html>
```

Because of this extraction and isolation of data from the view, you're able to easily modify **either** for repurpose. If you want to display new data, you only need to modify the data (`$content`) in order to display it the same way. Similarly, you can display the same data in multiple different places; in the above, `$content` can be outputted anywhere.

This not only **dramatically** increases manageability, but also cuts down on the amount of data stored in the database, resulting in less calls (and thus a faster load).

There's a plethora of different techniques in this regard, but the most common is the **[Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)** approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to enlighten me a little! I'd like to understand what it was you said that got you downvoted - the fact that you responded to something the 'community' thought you shouldn't respond to? At least it puts me on the right track to understanding the topic better, thanks!